# How to dynamically build a img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following view inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
<td id = "@item.RESOURCEID">
       @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateOnTMS","VirtualMachine", new AjaxOptions {
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
         UpdateTargetId =   item.RESOURCEID.ToString() ,
    LoadingElementId = item.RESOURCEID.ToString(),
         HttpMethod = "POST"})){
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <span class="f"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.VirtualMachine.RoleID)</span>
         <span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.VirtualMachine.ServerID)</span>
            @Html.Hidden("ResourceID", item.RESOURCEID)
         <input type="submit" value="Add To TMS" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            <img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id = item.RESOURCEID.ToString()/>
        }
</td>
```

But I need to create a loading imag dynamically and assign it the resourceID, but doing so will not work and the loading imag will not load when clicking on the Ajax.BeginForm. any idea what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not writing out the correct ID.  Try this:

```
<img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="@(item.RESOURCEID.ToString())" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply it worked for the imag tag. but if I write the same expression insde the Ajax.Beginform LoadingElementId = "@(item.RESOURCEID.ToString())" . then the generated html will take the expression ="@(item.RESOURCEID.ToString())" as a static string , unlike the imag tag .

Comment: @JohnJohn What you had originally for the Ajax form was correct.  Have a quick look at [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) razor syntax reference.  It will help you to understand when to use the different types of syntax.